# Can cypress.io test modern SharePoint webparts?

Tags: testing, sharepoint, automated-tests, cypress, web-parts

Now I'm in the stage where I need to pick a test automation tool to use it on a project built on modern SharePoint.
And of course this will include testing out of the box webparts and SharePoint provided webparts.
So my question is ,does cypress.io can handle testing webparts as after a lot of researches I found articles said that it can't until now.
And I'm still struggling with making cypress to login to my SharePoint tenant.
Any info about these will be really helpful